# Nagios send notification when back in notification_period

Tags: nagios

I have disabled notifications during certain time periods, like so:

```
define timeperiod{  
        timeperiod_name test  
        alias           Except test Hours  
        monday          08:20-08:15  
            [etc..] 
        sunday          08:20-08:15  
        }
```

So if a service goes down between 08:15-08:20, I don't get notified via mail. It just happened today that the service remained down for another 2 hours, and I was expecting to get an email when it's back in the notification_period.
How do I tell Nagios to send a notification email if it fits the notification times and the state of the service is still Critical?

**EDIT:**
My first approach was incorrect, so I followed an advice and used exclude periods like so:

```
define timeperiod{
        timeperiod_name test2
        alias           test2
        use             24x7
        exclude         test
}

define timeperiod{
        timeperiod_name test
        alias           Except test Hours
        thursday        12:15-12:25   # it was thursday when I tested
        }
```

and the service check:

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        service_description             TEST
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_TEST
        host_name                       some.host.here
        notification_period            test2
        }
```

and the service template:

```
define service{
        name                            generic-service
        active_checks_enabled           1              
        passive_checks_enabled          1              
        parallelize_check               1              
        obsess_over_service             1              
        check_freshness                 1              
        notifications_enabled           1              
        event_handler_enabled           1              
        flap_detection_enabled          0              
        failure_prediction_enabled      1              
        process_perf_data               1              
        retain_status_information       1              
        retain_nonstatus_information    1              
        is_volatile                     0              
        check_period                    24x7           
        max_check_attempts              2              
        check_interval                  120s           
        retry_interval                  60s            
        contact_groups                  admins         
        notification_options            w,u,c,r        
        notification_interval           120s           
        notification_period             24x7           
        register                        0              
        }
```

But I still don't get notified. I do get notified, however, if I manually reschedule the service check OR if I reload nagios.

Comment: Does it log anything specific when a notification doesn't go out due to time period restrictions?

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: I *think* it will only reschedule for a valid time if the notification_interval is non-zero. But what exact version of Nagios are you running?

Comment: Indeed, someone suggested I use exclude periods. I'm updating my original message with what I did. Version is Nagios Core 3.2.3.